# How to map a nullable enum to an integer in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hbmxml

I have an `enum` (which values are bit flags) as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum ItemType
{
    InventoryPart = 0x1,
    Service = 0x2,
    Discount = 0x4,
    NonInventory = 0x8,
    MiscellaneousCharge = 0x10,
    InventoryAssembly = 0x20,
    DescriptionLine = 0x40,
    All = InventoryPart | Service | Discount | NonInventory | MiscellaneousCharge | InventoryAssembly | DescriptionLine,
}
```

Then I have entity (`Item`) with a property on it (note: `ItemType` is `nullable`):

```
 private ItemType? _itemType;
 public ItemType? ItemType { get { return _itemType; } set { _itemType = value; } }
```

I am mapping this property as follows in the `hbm.xml` file:

```
<property name="ItemType" type="Int32" column="ItemType" not-null="false" />
```

In the database, this field is an integer (that allows nulls).

When I run the code, I get an exception from NHibernate library:

> Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter
> of PrlSystems.AccountingLibrary.Model.Item

NOTE:
When this property (`Item.ItemType`) was not a `nullable` before, everything worked, making this property `nullable` causes the exception mentioned above. Also, for built in types like `int`s, `DateTime`s, `nullable` class properties of these types can be mapped straight to their concrete types: `int`, `DateTime`.

I have tried mapping it this way but it still doesn't work:

```
System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32]]
```

What should the correct NHibernate mapping be now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after looking at this issue in more detail the main cause of this problem is the fact that:

**You cannot cast an Enum value to an (int?), you can only cast it to (int).**

To resolve this problem, I wrote a custom enum mapper by implementing IUserType interface. In there, I handle nullable enums expliclity.